# PublishSingleFile error on upgrading from netcoreapp3.1 to net6.0

Tags: .net, runtime, .net-6.0, cakebuild

I am getting this below error while trying to publish my app via the command line after upgrading it from netcoreapp3.1 to net6.0:

`dotnet cake build/build.cake --target=Publish --Verbosity=Diagnostic --runtimeIdentifier=win-x64`

Results:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateBundle" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\FolderHost\obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\singlefilehost.exe'. [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'C:\FolderHost\obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\singlefilehost.exe' [C:\\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite) [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.BinaryUtils.CopyFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.GenerateBundle(IReadOnlyList`1 fileSpecs) [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateBundle.ExecuteCore() [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(898,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\FolderHost\ProjectFileHost.csproj]
An error occurred when executing task 'Publish'.
Error: .NET CLI: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

Property Group of ProjectFileHost.csproj :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx</AssemblyName>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

PublishArtifacts code in operations.cake :

```
void PublishArtifact(string projPath, string runtime, string artfDir)
{
  DotNetCorePublishSettings pub = new DotNetCorePublishSettings()
  {
     Framework = "net6.0",
     Runtime =  runtime,
     PublishSingleFile = true,
     Configuration =  "Release",
     NoBuild = true,
     NoRestore = true,
     OutputDir = artfDir + "/" + runtime
  };

  DotNetCorePublish(projPath, pub);
}
```

If we make `PublishSingleFile  = false`, Publish command is working and creating application and dll files in Artifacts. But we need to publish the app in one single .exe file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set `NoBuild` & `NoRestore` to `false`?
Does it make any difference if you use the latest .NET 6 SDK (ATM 6.0.302)

Comment: No. It still produces the same error.

Comment: @Subhankar Is there another exe created, on build in the folder `C:\FolderHost\obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\`?

Does publish work on the commandline when you run `dotnet publish`´manually?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a cake error, it's an msbuild error. The file `C:\FolderHost\obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\singlefilehost.exe` does not exist to be deployed.

My guess is, since you have set `NoBuild = true` in your `DotNetCorePublishSettings`, that the project was not build (in the required configuration) beforehand.

You can either set `NoBuild = false, NoRestore = false` or you need to run `DotNet[Core]Build()` before publishing.

Also, please note that the `DotNetCore***` aliases have been deprecated in favor of new `DotNet***` aliases [in Cake 2.0.0](https://cakebuild.net/blog/2021/11/cake-v2.0.0-released#improvements-to-aliases-for-dotnet).

Comment: Setting `NoBuild = false, NoRestore = false` is not helping and leading to the same error. Before publishing, I am already running  `DotNet[Core]Build()` and build is working fine. Still after that Publish leading to the same error. 
And yes, The file `C:\FolderHost\obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\singlefilehost.exe` does not exist to be deployed. I have a apphost file in the same directory.

Comment: @Subhankar do you have a demo project that I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Setting PublishSingleFile to true in the property Group of ProjectFileHost.csproj created the singlefilehost.exe

```
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
```